# Incorrect user/pass rejection takes a long time from node/express/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication

I'm using an express API in node for mongodb access.  My auth route works fine when the user/pass is correct.  But when the user/pass is incorrect, the mongod instance issues this message 60 times:

```
2020-11-12T14:52:31.769-0500 I NETWORK  [conn181] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49487 conn181: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.5.7" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "19.6.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v11.0.0, LE (unified)" }
2020-11-12T14:52:31.770-0500 I ACCESS   [conn181] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for badUser on test_db from client 127.0.0.1:49487 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user badUser@test_db
2020-11-12T14:52:31.770-0500 I NETWORK  [conn181] end connection 127.0.0.1:49487 (0 connections now open)
```

...then my node/express API finally returns

`Authentication failed MongoServerSelectionError: Authentication failed.`

This is correct, but takes about 20 seconds to complete.  Therefore the user's time is wasted waiting for the 'incorrect user/pass' message.

Here is the connect code in node:

```
var auth = { user:encodeURIComponent(req.body.user), password:encodeURIComponent(req.body.pass) }
var clientOptions = { authSource:dbName, auth:auth, authMechanism:'DEFAULT', useUnifiedTopology:true}
client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_SERVER_URI, clientOptions)

client.connect((err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({err:`Authentication failed`}))
    return
  } 
}
```

Why is mongodb (or MongoClient) taking so long to reject the login?

Comment: That's interesting. I'd ask in the [developers forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/). But you should test this before asking: does it happen the same if you run using `mongo` binary?

Comment: JIC [`reconnectTries`: 30 _optional_](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/MongoClient.html#connect).

Comment: @Minsky thanks for pointing me.  Using ```mongo``` did not exhibit undesired behavior.  Tried using ```reconnectTries``` but got error 'not available in unified topology'  So removed ```useUnifiedTopology:true``` option.  Now works as expected.

Comment: That was a good thing, you're welcome dude